# How to validate 2 times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can sucess First page's Laravel validation. After that page I would like to put another data input and I need to validate the data. Here is my code. When I click submit buttom there I backed First page. Could you teach me what is wrong my code?

```
// This page's validation is OK.
 public function confirm(Request $request)
{
   $rules = [
   'orderer' => 'required'
  ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules); 
    $data = $request->all(); 
    $request->session()->put('data',$data); 
    return view('front.confirm', compact("data"));
}

// problem is here
public function complete(Request $request)
 { 
   $rules = [
'num' => "required|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
  ];

   $this->validate($request, $rules);   
   $data = $request->session()->pull('data');
   $token = array_shift($data);
   $data = array_merge($data, $request->all());
   $Contact = Contact::create($data);

 }
```

UPDATES 2

web.php

```
Route::post('mail/complete','MailController@complete');
```

complete.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="http://test.ivory.ne.jp/order/public/mail/complete">

<div class="form-group">

<select class="form-control" name="p1q" value="{{ old('p1q') }}">
<option value="-" selected>select </option>
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
            <option value="3" >3</option>           
</select>   
　　</div>


<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">送信</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Your first validation is pretty much pointless, since there are no validation rules defined. You could skip this. How does your form look like? Can you provide the HTML Markup of the form you are sending for validation?

Comment: @mynd I appreciate your help. Sorry yes I off 1st validation I was testing 2nd validaton so I turn off 1st one. I fixed it. And I update HTML part. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating the code. So it seems that your are trying to validate a field `num` which is not present on your `$request` object, since the `name` attribute of your HTML `<select>` is set to `p1q`.

So in order to make your validation function work, you need to either set

```
$rules = [
'p1q' => "required|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", //mind the changed field name change from "num" to "p1q"
  ];
```

or adapt your HTML markup to `<select name="num" ... >`.

Comment: Sorry for took long time. Thank you for answer. Yes I forgot the rules. I fixed it. But result is same. I was guessing something wrong under the $rule section. Is it all right ? And when I click a submit buttom of the page why I backed first data input page? Can't I validate data here after 1st validate data?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML Markup including the actual <form> block and your routes `web.php` entries? Not sure whether I totally understand your comment.

Comment: Thank you again. I update what you said part again. Could you look at it please?

Comment: Thank you. I can imagine two possible issues, but let's first try this one: I guess something is off within your `$this->validate()` method. For some reason I overlooked that it's not the default $request->validate() method I thought it is.

Maybe for testing purposes you should stick to laravels offical `$request->validate()` method first, as found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic. 

I guess you are somehow using it in your own `validate` method anyways, right? If so, please provide the code for this method as well.